# Linq to casted to object

Tags: c#, linq

Why is this code good:

```
var rowsfilterdbyvaluemembercolumn =
    this.PrimaryDataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<object>(this.ValueMemberColumn) == value);
```

And this code not good:

```
var rowsfilterdbyvaluemembercolumn =
    this.PrimaryDataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>(this.ValueMemberColumn) == Convert.ToInt32(value));
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: What type of value in 1 case?

Comment: I get no error, but the var rowsfilterdbyvaluemembercolumn is empty.

Comment: Can I fix this, because i don't non which type is in the DataSource?

Answer (score 3):

Because the first, `r.Field<object>` treats the value as an object and therefore does a reference comparison on `value`. Because the two aren't the same object, they compare as unequal.

The second converts `this.ValueMemberColumn` to an integer, and does a value comparison against the integer that you created by calling `ToInt32`.

See [Equality Comparisons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx) in the C# Programming Guide for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two ints as objects, this is what happens: The compiler generates code to box the two ints so that they are now reference types. So they are now treated as objects, and the compiler is looking for an == operator overload on this type. The object type doesn't have that, so it falls back to a reference comparison (it doesn't call Equals). Even if the ints were equal, they are always boxed as two instances. So they are not equal references now, and they are not treated as equal.